# Resharper Solution Wide Analysis shows 58 errors on starter ASP.NET Core 1.1 App

Tags: asp.net-core, resharper

Using Resharper 2017.1 and Visual Studio 2017 15.2, I have solution wide analysis turned on. After creating an ASP.NET Core 1.1 App with Individual Authorization, the analyzer shows 58 errors in 5 files. None of these errors seem to be legit as I can build and run it just fine.

Anyone else have this issue? Any resolutions?

I expanded on some of the errors here:[image: Resharper Solution Wide Analysis Errors]

Comment: When it is a product defect, talk to its vendor.

Comment: I don't know if it's a product defect. Hence the question.

Comment: @Reza if you clear R# caches via ReSharper | Options | Environment | General | Clear Caches and reload the solution - will it help?

Comment: I believe clearing the cache helped. Thanks!